# Change point detection with Matlab

Tags: time-series, matlab, mean, change-point, univariate

I'd like to detect changes in mean in time series data. I've been using R successfully with the ecp (cp3o) and BreakoutDetection libraries. I need to transfer my code from R to Matlab and are therefor looking for similar, or any, change detection methods so I don't have to start from scratch.

I've gone through Matlabs toolbox library and havn't found anything so far. The data could be seen as periodically stationary with noise. The changes will probably be larger than 2 standard deviations from the mean. Outliers should be minimal and can mostly be removed in preprocessing.

I'd be thankfull for any tips on how I could do the change detection quickly and easy with Matlab.

Kindly
Gustaf

Comment: Have you considered CART models?

Comment: I havn't but I think it could work. I'll give it a try.
I implemented CUSUM which was very easy :) and it works quite well for what I need.

Comment: I like that there are AICc formulations for CART, so there is some information theory indicating when a transition has occurred, even if your data is sparse.

Comment: @EngrStudent do you have any links for CART models in this context?

Comment: @blockwave - stacks.  do you have a preferred language or architecture? MatLab, java .. other?

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody still needs an answer, newer versions of Matlab has an internal function `findchangepts` for changepoint detection. But if anybody needs a Bayesian alternative, one possible tool in Matlab is the `BEAST` method my team developed, which is available at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72515-bayesian-changepoint-detection-time-series-decomposition. Unlike classical algorithms such as `findchangepts`, `BEAST` tells not just when the changepoints occur but also quantifies the probability of changepoint occurrence. See below for a quick illustration.

It can be installed by running

```
eval(  webread( 'http://b.link/rbeast', weboptions('cert','') )  );
```

Then, here is a quick test:

```
 load('Nile.mat')                                   % annual streamflow of the Nile River startin from year 1871
 out = beast(Nile, 'season', 'none','start', 1871)  % trend-only data without seasonality
 printbeast(out)
 plotbeast(out)
```

Given below is the plotting of the example. There is one significant changepoint (vertical line) attributed to the dam construction in the Nile River. The second subplot `Pr(tcp)` gives the changepoint occurrence probability over time where the peak corresponds to the changepoint.

[image]

More details about the toolbox are also available at https://github.com/zhaokg/Rbeast.